# entity framework join tables c#

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework

```
 void load_data()
    {
        DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
        var query = context.books.Include("category").Select(p => new
        {
            p.id,
            p.namebook,
            p.Price,
            p.picture,
            p.categoiryid,
            title= p.category.title,
        }).OrderByDescending(p => p.id).Take(8).ToList();
        ListView1.DataSource = query;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    } }
```

> 

```html
                        <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
                            <h3><a href="#"><%# Eval("namebook")%></a></h3>
                            <h3><a href="#"> ژانرکتاب:<%# Eval("title")%>0</a></h3>

                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div class="pricing">
                                    <p class="price"><span><%# Eval("price")%> تومان</span></p>
                                </div>
```

**I want to join the table books and table category.
The title is not shown to me in the output.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5rSj.jpg)

Comment: you have to post  book and category classes too

Comment: the include should bring in the category date by reference.  the title should be showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that relations between tables are not properly configured. Try this syntax

```
var query = (from p in context.Set<Book>()
            join c in context.Set<Category>()
                on p.categoryId equals c.id
            select new {    
            p.id,
            p.namebook,
            p.Price,
            p.picture,
            p.categoiryid,
            c.titel,
            }).OrderByDescending(p => p.id).Take(8).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code worked correctly.

Comment: And yet another answer using `join` while `join` should rarely be used in EF LINQ queries. OP should use the navigation property `book.category` that's already there.